# Decode protobuf without proto files in python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protobuf.js, protobuf-python

I would like to decode protobuf.

Example of the protobuf data: `0a06282c0241057a10011805220d080510bea3f493062a03010c1628f1a6f493063002382b4001481482010f383634333233303532343736343839`

I can Decoding online (e.g. via https://protobuf-decoder.netlify.app/) works fine.

The website decode Protobuf without having the original .proto files. And all decoding is done locally via JavaScript (Contribute on [GitHub](https://github.com/pawitp/protobuf-decoder)).

How can I do this in python?

I try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275458/12780274) but not exist .proto file.

Comment: May help you: https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/encoding/

Answer (score 0):

Take the raw decoding from that site and you write a `.proto` file yourself.

For example, taking the first rows of the output:

```
Byte Range  Field Number    Type    Content
0-8                 1       string  (,Az
8-10                2       varint  As Int: 1
                                    As Signed Int: -1
10-12               3       varint  As Int: 5
                                    As Signed Int: -3
```

you would write:

```
message MyMessage {
    string field1 = 1;
    int32 field2 = 2;
    int32 field3 = 3;
}
```

Once you figure out what the fields actually mean, you can assign more sensible names instead of `fieldX`. If you aren't interested in some of the fields, you can leave them out of the .proto file and the protobuf decoder will ignore them.

Comment: How can I use proto file? Which module?

Comment: @henrry Read any Python protobuf tutorial, for example https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/